# How to pass list as parameter in parallel process using concurrent.futures

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have the following codes. In principle, I'd like to iterate `long_list`
and apply a function `procedure()`, which takes a value and another list `short_list` as parameter:

```
def procedure(par1, the_short_list):
    """
    Description of procedure
    """
    o1, o2 = par1.split(" ")
    out = []
    for sl in the_short_list:
        output = sl * int(o1) * int(o2)
        out.append(output)
    return out



long_list = [str(v) + " " + str(w) for v, w in enumerate(range(0,10))]
short_list = range(10,15)

#--------------------------------------------------
# Sequential
#--------------------------------------------------
for i in long_list:
    out = procedure(i, short_list)
    print  (out)
```

It produces this result:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[40, 44, 48, 52, 56]
[90, 99, 108, 117, 126]
[160, 176, 192, 208, 224]
[250, 275, 300, 325, 350]
[360, 396, 432, 468, 504]
[490, 539, 588, 637, 686]
[640, 704, 768, 832, 896]
[810, 891, 972, 1053, 1134]
```

Now what I want to do is to parallelize the process by breaking the `long_list` and run `procedure()` in parallel and finally gather the results.

I tried this code:

```
#--------------------------------------------------
# Parallel
#--------------------------------------------------
import concurrent.futures
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    future = executor.submit(procedure, long_list, short_list)
    print(future.result())
```

But it gives this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 33, in <module>
    print(future.result())
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 462, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 63, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 6, in procedure
    o1, o2 = par1.split(" ")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

What's the right way to do it?

I expect the output to be the same with sequential version. And when apply with much larger `long_list` it will run faster.

Comment: The first parameter should be string not list

Comment: @Samuel What's the construct to do that, in my case?

Comment: Why are you concatenating `str(v) + " " + str(w)` and then splitting `o1, o2 = par1.split(" ")`? Wouldn't it be easier to send two arguments instead?

Comment: @zvone This is to mimic the actual data as close as possible. The actual data long list contains some text.

Answer (score 1):

This one should work for you:

```
import concurrent.futures

futures = []
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for entry in long_list: 
         futures.append(executor.submit(procedure, entry, short_list))
for future in futures:
    print(future.result())
```

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to speed up the parallel. I tried up to `100000` at long list. But the timing is slower for parallel version: `24.272919 seconds` versus `0.54323 seconds` sequential

Comment: Since looks you do CPU bounded tasks you may hit GIL limitation, when working with Python's threads. Try ProcessPoolExecutor